# Operation of common algorithms and data structures

Tags: data-structures

[image: According to:]

I think the data-structure here is a queue, because it removes the oldest element from the list. What do you think?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions should be self contained

Comment: I can't put the image in the question, I don't know why.

Comment: Don't put image. Write it down.

Comment: That's a stack, Last In First Out

Comment: @Fil: re-read the question. 1, 12, and 5 are inserted, then an item is removed. According to the question, 1 is the first item removed. The output is in the same order as the input, which means that it's FIFO: first in, first out. If it were a stack, the order would be reversed.

Comment: It is definitely a Queue data-structure, I've explained why is so in my answer, you can check that out. By the way, it would be nice if you provide better questions extended with sample codes and also questions should be more specific so that users can help you easily.

Answer (score -1):

This is exactly a **Queue** data-structure ( **First-In-First-Out** ). Notify that all the inserted items are added to the **tail** and all removed items are removed from the **head**.

#### States of the Sequence

```
List    : 1 12 5
Removed : -

- After First Remove ( * )
List    : 12 5
Removed : 1

- After Second Remove ( * * * )
List    : 7
Removed : 1 12 5 3

- After Third Remove ( * )
List    : 2 4 13
Removed : 1 12 5 3 7

- After Fourth Remove ( * * * )
List    : 14 15
Removed : 1 12 5 3 7 2 4 13
```

#### A Java Test Code

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;

public class QueueDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Integer> removed = new LinkedList<>();

        queue.add(1);
        queue.add(12);
        queue.add(5);

        System.out.println("After First Insert");
        System.out.println("Queue: " + queue);
        System.out.println();

        removed.add(queue.poll());

        System.out.println("After First Remove ( * )");
        System.out.println("Queue   : " + queue);
        System.out.println("Removed : " + removed);
        System.out.println();

        queue.add(3);
        queue.add(7);

        removed.add(queue.poll());
        removed.add(queue.poll());
        removed.add(queue.poll());

        System.out.println("After Second Remove ( * * * ) ");
        System.out.println("Queue   : " + queue);
        System.out.println("Removed : " + removed);
        System.out.println();

        queue.add(2);
        queue.add(4);
        queue.add(13);

        removed.add(queue.poll());

        System.out.println("After Third Remove ( * ) ");
        System.out.println("Queue   : " + queue);
        System.out.println("Removed : " + removed);
        System.out.println();

        queue.add(14);
        queue.add(15);

        removed.add(queue.poll());
        removed.add(queue.poll());
        removed.add(queue.poll());

        System.out.println("After Fourth Remove ( * * * ) ");
        System.out.println("Queue   : " + queue);
        System.out.println("Removed : " + removed);
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

#### Output of the Test Code

```
After First Insert
Queue: [1, 12, 5]

After First Remove ( * )
Queue   : [12, 5]
Removed : [1]

After Second Remove ( * * * ) 
Queue   : [7]
Removed : [1, 12, 5, 3]

After Third Remove ( * ) 
Queue   : [2, 4, 13]
Removed : [1, 12, 5, 3, 7]

After Fourth Remove ( * * * ) 
Queue   : [14, 15]
Removed : [1, 12, 5, 3, 7, 2, 4, 13]
```